# Combining data.frames in R based off a character list

Tags: r, rbind

I have multiple data.frames that I want to rbind together using R. I also have a character vector with the names of each of these data.frames. What I'm looking to do is use this character vector to determine which data.frames to bind together.

For example, I have 5 similar data.frames below and I want to bind the first 3 data.frames using the character list somehow. Is it possible to use this character vector to rbind these data.frames?

```
# Create List 
l <- c( "list1","list2","list3")

# Data Frames
list1 <- data.frame(
  Name="Test1",
  Data="Test1"
)

list2 <- data.frame(
  Name="Test2",
  Data="Test2"
)

list3 <- data.frame(
  Name="Test3",
  Data="Test3"
)

list4 <- data.frame(
  Name="Test4",
  Data="Test4"
)

list5 <- data.frame(
  Name="Test5",
  Data="Test5"
)

# Rbind data.frames ?
dat <- rbind( l[1], l[2], l[3] )
dat

# Loop and rbind ? 
df <- data.frame()
for( i in 1:length(l)) {
  print( l[i] )
  df[i] <- rbind( df, l[i] )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result = do.call(rbind, args = mget(l))` should work.

`mget` returns a `list()` of the objects from your global environment. `do.call(fun, list)` is how we write `fun(list[[1]], list[[2]], ...)`.

As a side-note, I'd suggest not using the word "list" to refer to vectors--save it for `list` class objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mget` + `dplyr::bind_rows`:

```r
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(mget(l))

   Name  Data
1 Test1 Test1
2 Test2 Test2
3 Test3 Test3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mget(l))
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
join_all(list(df1,df2,df3,df4), by = 'commun_character_vector', type = 'full')
```

Comment: I think a key part of this question is that OP has many data frames, not just 2.

Comment: This sadly doesn't work dynamically